# how to keep the first cell always active in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

How to keep the first cell always active when opening the excel sheet.

Can any one guide me to how to this.

This is my
 code:

```
       Private Sub Send_Click()
       Dim strURL As String
       strURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/excelAPI.php?customer_id=1&mobilenumber=" _
       & ActiveCell.Value & "&message=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
       Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebBrowser4.Navigate(strURL)

       End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you would want the first cell to be active. If it's just because you are using *ActiveCell* in your Code then you should be defining a Range instead. Like this:

```
Private Sub Send_Click()
   Dim strURL As String
   strURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/excelAPI.php?customer_id=1&mobilenumber=" _
   & Range("A1").Value & "&message=" & Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value
   Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebBrowser4.Navigate(strURL)
End Sub
```

Anyway. This is how you activate the first cell (A1) of *YourWorksheet* when the Workbook is opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
   Worksheets("YourWorksheet").Activate
   Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i tried but it not taking the cell A1 while closing the excel it asking Save i dont want to ask it every time

Comment: You _could_ disable the save dialog with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. However it's not always a good idea since users expect a save dialog when they are closing a modified worksheet.

Comment: ok when i am closing the excel i will save the action that performed .again open the excel sheet it will perform the last action.how to stop that.i want the action when button is clicked