# How to active action in vba while opening the excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

i want to active particular cell using vba while opening  the excel.

Can anyone guide me how to do  it.

Thanks

```
        Private Sub Send_Click()
        Dim strURL As String
      strURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/excelAPI.php?customer_id=1&mobilenumber=" _
        & ActiveCell.Value & "&message=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
      Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebBrowser4.Navigate(strURL)

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      End Sub

       Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range ("A1")
        End Sub
```

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Once you close the workbook there is not question of cell being active or deactive. If you wanna a particular cell to be active when you open the workbook then use workbook_open event.

Comment: ok can you tell me how to activate the particular cell when opening excel .i tried its not working .i pasted my code

Comment: Its already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382801/how-to-keep-the-first-cell-always-active-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: when i press the button the action will perform then i close the excel it asking for save or not when i click save it save .then when i open the excel sheet it will perform the action without clicking the button .can you tell me how to stop this

Comment: why did you take off this line `Range("A1").Activate` ? Tell me what you dont understand in the code ?

Comment: when i press the button the action will perform then i close the excel it asking for save or not when i click save it save .then when i open the excel sheet it will perform the action without clicking the button .can you tell me how to stop this.i am new to vba

Comment: did you understand what i am try to say

Comment: when you open the workbook only `Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
   Worksheets("YourWorksheet").Activate
   Range("A1").Activate
End Sub` part of code will run. It means when the workbook is opened it will activate the fist cell for you as per your requirement.

Comment: your  `Send_Click()` will not be called when you open the workbook.

Comment: this is my new code but it automatically sent message when it open          Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate Range("A1").Activate

End Sub
Private Sub Send_Click()
Dim strURL As String
strURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/excelAPI.php?customer_id=1&mobilenumber=" _
   & ActiveCell.Value & "&message=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebBrowser4.Navigate(strURL)


End Sub

Comment: Can you upload your file on a drive and get me the link so that i understand what exactly is your issue.

Comment: thia is all my code when your select the cell and click the button it will send sms its working fine.after that i close the excel and open it again message send automatically send to the number it sends before do you how to stop that

Comment: `@Send_Click()` will not be called automatically when you open the workbook unless there is any magic.

Comment: no it performing the previous action ,that means the last action before closing the excel that same action perform automatically while opening the excel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382801/how-to-keep-the-first-cell-always-active-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: it performing the previous action ,that means the last action before closing the excel.same action perform automatically while opening the excel

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want `Send_Click` to run when the workbook is opened, you just call it in the `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    Send_Click
End Sub
```

Please note that `Workbook_Open` needs to be in the `ThisWorkbook` module, but `Send_Click` can be in a different module.

You should also think about referencing the cell you want directly instead of selecting a cell and then using `ActiveCell`. It will be a lot faster and a lot easier to avoid mistakes. See this [Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/1490783).

Answer (score 0):

To activate a cell you need to select it first. Also if the sheet isn't active this also needs activating.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
```

**Can I suggest** if the data in cell `A1` is what you are after in the `send_click` procedure you reference it directly like so:

```
Private Sub Send_Click()    
    Dim strURL As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").
        strURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/excelAPI.php?customer_id=1&mobilenumber=" _
        & .Value & "&message=" & .Offset(0, 1).Value
    end with

    Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebBrowser4.Navigate(strURL)        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False    
End Sub
```

Comment: can you tell me how to deactivate the previous action when opening the excel

Comment: the only way to do this is to save in memory what was selected previously and re-select that. De-activate doesn't exist just activating another.

Comment: im not sure I understand what you mean by deactivate.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to tell excel what cell to get its information from in the `send_click` procedure? It seems this is the only place your using the information from `A1`.

Comment: i am new to vba this my first program in excel vba.i asked question here    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393929/how-to-deactive-the-previous-action-in-vba-while-opening-the-excel

Comment: what other code is in there?